# Did ScrollViewer change between 8.1 and 10?

Tags: xaml, scrollview, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a Windows 8.1 Store app I am moving to 10 as a Universal app. On 8.1 it works fine. On 10 (both Windows and Phone) it will not scroll. You can see a viewport worth of entries, but it stubbornly refuses to show a scrollbar on mouseover, move if you drag with your finger on a touch screen, scroll when I use the down arrow key to move from item to item, or respond to mouse wheel if there's a mouse - all of which the 8.1 version does.

**Has something happened between 8.1 and 10 that might cause this?**

There are a number of ScrollViewers in the system and they all do this. Here is one, implicitly on a gridview:

```
<GridView
            x:Name="itemListViewSnapped"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
            Grid.Row="5"
            Margin="20,5,10,0"
            Padding="10,0,0,60"
            Background="{StaticResource TimeBucketsSections}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ItemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Bucket80ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBucketViewModel}"
            SelectionChanged="ItemGridViewSelectionChanged"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
            Visibility="{Binding BucketsVisable}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
            ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False">
```

I'm leaving all the binding and background and whatnot in there on the offchance they're relevant. The `ScrollViewer.` parts are what matter, imo.

Comment: strange. Do the Scollviewers work when not part of a GridView or ListView?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have any loose ones (this app is low on text)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help but I have had issues with `ScrollViewer` when in a `GridView`. I usually wrap the element in a ScrollViewer and turn the one in the GridView off for more stable behaviour.

```
<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
     <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
    </GridView>
</ScrollViewer>
```